# Quartz Scheduler. How do I know that trigger will not trigger anymore?

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler

I have simple console application that performs a job in a background on regular basis and waits user to press a key.

I use [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org) library for scheduler and have code like that:

```
schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
scheduler.Start();       

myTrigger = TriggerUtils.MakeDailyTrigger(..., ...);
myJob = new JobDetail(..., null, typeof(MyJobClass));
scheduler.ScheduleJob(myJob, myTrigger);

Console.WriteLine("Press 'Q' to exit");
while (Console.ReadKey() != new ConsoleKeyInfo('q', ConsoleKey.Q, false, false, false))
{
}
```

That works ok but for several conditions I configure trigger to execute once.

How can I know that my triggered job executed once and no jobs will fire ever with pure Quartz API ? I can use semaphore and low-level multithreading stuff for that but I guess there should be pure-Quartz approach.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can configure TriggerListner

or

Utilize API methods getPreviousFireTime() / getNextFireTime() / mayFireAgain() on Trigger